# Why is the JSON content property treated special when converted to XML?

Tags: java, json, xml, data-conversion, org.json

I'm using the available transformation functions in the org.json library to transform json to xml.  It's very simple to do like this.

```
String xmlStr = XML.toString(new JSONObject(jsonStr));
```

Everything was perfect until I needed to process some json that contained the content property like this.

```
{
    "content": "X",
    ...
}
```

I expected this to convert to

```
<content>X</content>
```

but instead it converts to simply X without the opening and closing tags.  So I checked the source code for XML.toString and "content" is treated special.  The comment in the code says this.

```
// Emit content in body
```

I Googled and also found this.

```
Content text may be placed in a "content" member
```

However I can't find an explanation of what this is all about.  What's the purpose and why would someone want this to be treated in a special way?  Also If you can point me to a good explanation that would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a non-optimal implementation decision. The most recent discussion have taken place in org.json issue [#394](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/issues/394#issuecomment-360675403):

> "content" is an unfortunately-named keyword in the XML <-> Java transformation. For the history of this issue, please see #344, #286, and #108. For more information about how the keyword works, see XMLTest.java contentOperations() in https://github.com/stleary/JSON-Java-unit-test.
>
> No objection if someone wants to propose a workaround along the lines of #108, or any other approach that does not break existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

There is [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.jsonToXml(json)`. It supports `content` key name. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
{
    "content": "X"
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>X</content>
```